# Big-O of a function example

Tags: big-o, code-complexity

I have this function:

```
function void myFoo(int num, int count) { 
    if (num == 0) return;

    for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        for (int y = x; y < count; y++) {
            for (int z = y; z < count; z++) {
                //O(1) computation
            }
        }
        num--;
        myFoo(num, count);
    }
}
```

and I'm just wondering about the complexity of this function,
is it Big-o (n!) ?

Comment: It depends. It might never finish. It might be O(2^n) or O(1) amortized.

Comment: This function will just recurse forever as there's no end condition. Could you provide a more concise example?

Comment: Please provide more details about the each `for` loop runs: initial values, how they change their loop variables after each iteration, and the loop conditions.

Comment: it is an "infinite recursion" as there is no end condition i.e; it represents  a stack so even the two internal for loops runs n^2 times and comes to call 'myFoo()' it actually creates the iteration from the beggining .So it causes an 'infinte nested loop' or 'infinite recursion' until unless you provide a break condition.

Comment: Its BigO is O(∞)

Comment: I just added the break condition

Comment: Still haven't specified what the loop conditions are. They could be infinite loops for all we know.

Comment: I have it now, you can check it out

Comment: It is still broken. E.g. if `num < count` you call `myFoo` with negative `num` and you will never stop. Also `count` seems not to count anything. Does it change in the `O(1)` operations?

Comment: `count` does not count anything other than determining how many times you go through the loops

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that `num` and `count` are both non-negative. The runtime T(m, n), with m, n being the sizes of `num` and `count` (i.e. log(`num`), log(`count`)), is given by

```
T(m, n)=sum(T(log(2^m-1), n)+sum(sum(O(1), z=y..2^n-1), y=x..2^n-1), x=0..2^n-1)
```

which simplifies to

```
T(m, n)=2^n*T(log(2^m-1), n)+2^n/3+2^(2n-1)+2^(3n-1)/3
```

giving

```
T(m, n)=2^n*T(log(2^m-1), n)+O(2^(3n))
```

Observing that this does not depend on m, except that it is recursively applied 2^m times, we get

```
T(m, n)=sum(2^(k*n)*O(2^(3n)), k=0..2^m-1)
```

which is the same as

```
T(m, n)=O((8^n*(-1 + 2^(2^m*n)))/(-1 + 2^n))=O(2^((2^m+2)n))=O(2^(2n)*2^(2^m*n))
```

So, measuring the input as the sizes of each number (and generalizing to allow for arbitrarily sized integers), the complexity is worse than double-exponential in m.